# Select query with fallback to basic item

Tags: mysql, select

I am sure that there is a way to do this, but I am unable to see how.

I have a table of items which are categorised :

```
table items
(
    item_name
    id_category
)
- item list -
"Item one", 1
"Item two", 2
"Item three", 3

table service
(
    service_name
    exclusive
    id_category
)
- service list -
"Basic service", 0, null
"Advanced service", 1, null
"Super service", 1, 2
```

I need to do a select on the service table to find the service which is specific to a given item.
It should always return a service which is not exclusive and not category specific.
It should ALSO return only the exclusive service which relates to its category OR when the id_category is null.

So the query for "Item one" should return

```
Basic Service
Advanced Service
```

and "Item two" should return

```
Basic Service
Super Service
```

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: This site is to help you get things done, not doing things for you.

Comment: @EH_watch - your comment is totally unhelpful ! The question presents a very simplified version of what I am trying to do.  The SELECT statements I have tried so far can only return either all the service list OR an incorrect list. Hence my question ...

Comment: have you tried a DECODE or CASE statement?

Comment: Hi @Randy, yes I tried CASE in the statement but was unable to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need a UNION

```
(SELECT `service_name` FROM `service` WHERE `exclusive`='0')
UNION
(SELECT IFNULL(`service`.`service_name`,(SELECT `service_name` FROM `service` WHERE `exclusive`='0' AND `id_category` IS NULL)) FROM `items` LEFT JOIN `service` ON `items`.`id_category`=`service`.`id_category` WHERE `items`.`name`='Item one')
```

Your WHERE clause on the second query might be different. I assume you are searching by item name

Comment: You sure that the OP doesn't need a `UNION ALL`?

Comment: Thankyou for the suggestion, just tried this and I am getting the services which are category specific and non specific.  What I need is that it "falls back" to non specific if the category is not found.

Comment: I just saw that. I think a left join and ifnull might get what you need. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Thank you for this Jon.  I see where you are going with this and am grateful for your help.  As you can imagine, this is not all I am needing to get.  In fact the queried table contains a number of fields that I need to return and not one single field.  I don't see how I can output a list of fields with this.

Comment: @JonHulka There is a performance difference between the two. `UNION` attempts to remove duplicates, thus takes more time, where `UNION ALL` will simply stack the two sets.